# CSS selector immedate sibling

Tags: html, css

I need a very specific css selector that will choose a button element in certain situations.  Only when a button **immediately** follows an `<input type="text">` element should the button be selected.

Below are 3 examples that show when a  element should be selected.  The last example shows a scenario where the button is not selected (as it does not immediately follow an `<input type="text">` element.

```
<!--button is selected-->
<div>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button></button>
</div>

<!--button is selected-->
<div>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button></button>
</div>

<!--button is selected-->
<div>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button></button>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button></button>
</div>

<!--button is not selected-->
<div>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <label>foo</label>
    <select></select>
    <button></button>
</div>

<!--first button selected, second button NOT selected-->
<div>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- input type selector
- attribute selector
- [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)
- button type selector

thus:

```
input[type=text] + button
```

Or, if you want to support all text inputs (since text is the default type), you'll need to add in a not clause on other kinds of input:

```
input[type=text] + button,
input:not([type]) + button {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `+` selector

```
p + div
```

Will select any DIV immediately after a P

Answer (score 1):

Adjacent Sibling is what you're looking for here. Something like this should do the trick:

```
input + button {
    /*do something*/
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing it off: http://jsfiddle.net/z1y7mvnk/

Answer (score 1):

As you want to select the buttons that are adjacent siblings of text type inputs, you'll need to combine an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), like so:

```
input[type=text]+button{
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to select all buttons that are adjacent siblings of any input with a similar function to that of a text input (e.g., password, number, etc.), you'll need to string together a few [negation pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), like so:

```
input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not(...)+button{
    /* your styles here */
}
```

In the above instance, it may just be simpler to give your inputs a classname instead and use the following selector:

```
input.class+button{
    /* your styles here */
}
```